# How to write JpaRepository method for searching Users that have phone number stored in Set<String>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I'm working on a Spring project and now i have to write JPA method for searching a users that have phone number LIKE in Set

The method should be in my interface UserRepository that implements `JpaRepository`

I have tried to write the method like:
`List<User> findByNameLikeOrPhoneNumbersLike(String name, Set<String> phoneNumbers);`
`List<User> findByNameLikeOrPhoneNumbersLike(String name, String phoneNumber);`
`List<User> findByNameLikeOrPhoneNumbersContaining(String name, String phoneNumber);`

But none of them works.

My class for the User Entity is:

```
@Entity
public class User  {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

 @Convert(converter = PhoneNumbersConverter.class)
    public Set<String> phoneNumbers = new TreeSet<>();

........
}
```

Currently my PhoneNumbersConverter converts the list to joined String with ","

**I want to write method that can search me Users on given string that may be the LIKE the name or may be LIKE one of the user Numbers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with using `nativeQuery` `@Query` you could do it like that (assuming that column names are `name`, `phone_numbers` and that `phone_numbers` looks like this `111222333,222333444,333444555`).

```
@Query(value = 
  "SELECT _user FROM user _user " +
  "WHERE " +
    "_user.name LIKE CONCAT('%', $1, '%') OR " +
    "_user.phone_numbers LIKE CONCAT('%', $1, '%')",
nativeQuery = true
)
List<User> findWhereNameOrPhoneNumberLike(String query);
```

You also might want to use `UPPER` function for both `query` and `_user.name` to be case-insensitive (`UPPER(_user.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', $1, '%'))`).

Comment: I've tried but I have exceptions for query Validation. After i set nativeQuery to true and i have exception for sql, because user.phoneNumbers is not a Table. My convert is saving it in User table as Joined string

Comment: @Bojmaliev i've edited my answer and posted how a native query should look like for this type of mapping. Of course details are dependent on the database which you are using, but try it out.